# PySide6 Convert ImageQt to QPixmap

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm converting old Python 2.7 code to Python 3 and get following error on the last line:

```
ar = imgArray*255
ar = numpy.clip(ar, 0, 255, out=ar)
img = Image.fromarray(ar.astype("uint8"))
qim = ImageQt.ImageQt(img)   
pm = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)


TypeError: 'PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt)
```

So, the question is: how to get QPixmap from ImageQt object in PySide6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pil.ImageQt decides the backend based on whether the library was imported, if it did, then it will use that otherwise there is an internal order (PyQt6, PySide6, PyQt5, PySide2 at this time). So to avoid these problems you have to first import PySide6 and then PIL.

```py
import PySide6
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui

import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageQt

import numpy as np

print(
    f"Tested with:\n- PIL version: {PIL.__version__},\n- PySide6 version: {PySide6.__version__},\n- Qt Version: {QtCore.qVersion()}\n- Numpy version: {np.__version__}"
)

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication()

ar = np.random.randint(255, size=(900, 800, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(ar.astype(np.uint8))
qim = ImageQt.ImageQt(img)
pm = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
assert not pm.isNull()
```

Output:

```
Tested with:
- PIL version: 8.3.1,
- PySide6 version: 6.1.2,
- Qt Version: 6.1.2
- Numpy version: 1.21.2
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I made clear new file with exactly your script and get the same error:   File "test_q.py", line 12, in <module>
    pm = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(QImage)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(Union[PySide6.QtGui.QImage, str], PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ImageConversionFlags=PySide6.QtCore.Qt.ImageConversionFlag.AutoColor)

Comment: @dmitry Try the latest versions of each library like the ones I indicate in my post. Also what is the output of `print(type(qim), qim)` before `pm = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
`

Comment: <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QImage'> <PyQt5.QtGui.QImage object at 0x00000261CDB944A8>

Comment: And for version print I got an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_q.py", line 14, in <module>
    f"Tested with:\n- PIL version: {PIL.__version__},\n- PySide6 version: {PySide6.__version__},\n- Qt Version: {QtCore.qVersion()}\n- Numpy version: {np.__version__}"
NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined

Comment: @dmitry in my code I use `import PIL`, Please use my code through copy-paste. It seems that you are not using the latest version of PIL or that you have imported PyQt5 first.

Comment: but I cannot get why need explicitly use import PIL, why from PIL import Image, ImageQt is not enough?